# Equivalent to ControllerBase's `IsLocalUrl` in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

So I normally have an endpoint in a controllerbase where I check if a given url is local or not with `Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)`, but I can't find an equivalent to use in a Blazor code behind. Does this just not exist yet? Using .NET 6 if that helps.

Comment: The question is unclear.  You have a controller in your Blazor wasm or your are calling a controller elsewhere?

Comment: should have said `i normally have an endpoint in a controllerbase`

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own implementation of **IsLocalUrl** based on the source code from UrlHelperBase: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/UrlHelperBase.cs

for example:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLocalUrl(this string? url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Allows "/" or "/foo" but not "//" or "/\".
        if (url[0] == '/')
        {
            // url is exactly "/"
            if (url.Length == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // url doesn't start with "//" or "/\"
            if (url[1] != '/' && url[1] != '\\')
            {
                return !HasControlCharacter(url.AsSpan(1));
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Allows "~/" or "~/foo" but not "~//" or "~/\".
        if (url[0] == '~' && url.Length > 1 && url[1] == '/')
        {
            // url is exactly "~/"
            if (url.Length == 2)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // url doesn't start with "~//" or "~/\"
            if (url[2] != '/' && url[2] != '\\')
            {
                return !HasControlCharacter(url.AsSpan(2));
            }

            return false;
        }

        return false;

        static bool HasControlCharacter(ReadOnlySpan<char> readOnlySpan)
        {
            // URLs may not contain ASCII control characters.
            for (var i = 0; i < readOnlySpan.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsControl(readOnlySpan[i]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
 string testurl = "/test";

 if (testurl.IsLocalUrl())
 {
     _NavigationManager.NavigateTo(testurl);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use NavigationManager :

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation;
bool isLocal = Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri(Navigation.Uri).IsLoopback;
```

Comment: IsLoopback is only correct when the Server runs on LocalHost. This won't work after a deployment.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NavigationManager.BaseUri`

```
@page "/base"
@page "/base/base"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>BaseUrl</PageTitle>

<div class="p-2">
    Url : @this.baseUrl
</div>

@code {
    private string baseUrl = string.Empty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.baseUrl = NavManager.BaseUri;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```